# Custom XML error with Android Build Tools (0.4.2) -- No resource identifier found for attribute 'gapWidth' in package 'xxx.xxxx.'

Tags: android

Updated to the latest Android Build tools (0.4.2) and ran into the following when attempting to assemble:

/AndroidApp/App/build/res/all/flavor/debug/layout/fragment.xml:84:
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'gapWidth' in package 'com.viewpagerindicator'

`RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/build/res/com.viewpagerindicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since flavors may use a different packagename, instead of specifying the package name in the custom namespace, use: 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto'.

Answer (score 1):

Update your custom XML link paths to use `build` instead of `apk`.

Was, in the fragment.xml file 
`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.viewpagerindicator"`

Now, to this: 
`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/build/res/com.viewpagerindicator"`

Comment: By trial and error -- I made an assumption based off my knowledge of the gradle build directory structure that fixed my issue.  @helpful harry's answer is better.

Comment: my issue was also with the viewpagerindicator library and was only when opening and trying to the compile the project on another developers environment. using /build/ here solved the issue and project now compiles. just curious to know how using /apk/ or /build/ affect the project and if things may be different when producing release builds.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the build folder should be generated irregardless of build type.